# jQuery autocomplete with many inputs - django-dynamic-formset

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-ui, django-forms

I'm using jQuery autocomplete feature (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete) and Django dynamic-formset (http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/).
One of my formset fields needs to use autocomplete, so I attach it using (simplified):

```
$('input[name$=select]').autocomplete({source:'my_url/', minLength: 3});
```

I call this on document ready and it works fine (gets data from ajax). However, if I add new row with django-dynamic-formset and handle its 'added' event with:

```
function(row){
    $(row).find('input[name$=select]').autocomplete({source:'my_url/', minLength: 3});
}
```

it doesn't work with newly added rows. What's wrong?

UPDATE:
Tried to use classes instead - no result
Tried to use on()/live() - no result
Tried to destroy autocomplete after new row is added - no result (it destroys, but does no create).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this code with jquery.formset-1.2 and it definitely works:

```
function enableAutocomplete(context) {
    $('input[name$=select]', context || null).autocomplete({source:'my_url/', minLength: 3});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.foo').formset({
        added: function(row) {
            enableAutocomplete(row);
        }
    });

    enableAutocomplete();
});
```

Comment: Yes, excatly. I've found the same solution by accident. It's a bit tricky, I had to change order (first run formset, then autocomplete). Otherwise formset copies inputs with autocomplete attached and this causes error.