# django-dynamic-formset and django-autocomplete-light integration bug

Tags: django, autocomplete, formset

Im using the latest packages of django-dynamic-formset and django-autocomplete-light to build a custom form (like the classic Order/Products example). 
Everything work, but when I create a new line this is created the double and I can’t fix it.
I think the problem is what the cloning method does. Someone can help me or has an example that works? Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the code you've tried so far? Also, please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have solved your problem.

I had the same problem and after hours of reading posts I finally found this [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686456/jquery-autocomplete-with-many-inputs-django-dynamic-formset).

You have to call the dynamic `formset` before `form.media`, of django autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

`django-autocomplete-light version 3.8.1` would solves your issue. It worked for me.